# Nothing spawning in The Nether, even from a blaze spawner. (on a server)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to kill some Wither Skeletons to be able to spawn The Wither, and kill it. But there's one slight issue. No Wither Skeletons are spawning ever, as a matter of fact nothing is spawning. So I went into the debug menu and NOTHING is in this dimension besides myself.
[image: The entity count from the debug menu.]

This is... interesting, there's the capability to spawn mobs, but nothing is spawning.

The local difficulty is: 2.25 // 0.13 so mobs should spawn, right?
This is also JE, not bedrock.

Comment: What's the difficulty set to? Is `gamerule doMobSpawning` turned on?

Comment: Yes, doMobSpawing is turned on. And I said the difficulty in the post (maybe local difficulty doesn't do anything) but it's on normal diff.

Comment: Then maybe the mob cap is filled somewhere else, in chunks that are loaded on the server, but not on your client. Those could for example be the spawn chunks in the Overworld.

Comment: Are spawn chunks always loaded? What's the default mob cap?

Comment: Yes, spawn chunks are usually loaded. There are some edge cases, but those depend on the version. If you have a player anywhere in the Overworld, I think it should load the spawn chunks in 1.14.4. The mob cap is a more complicated subject, let's say something around 100 or so. Maybe just 50. It depends on a lot of factors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a server talk to the owner, they could have disabled nether or if on a server by yourself try resetting nether or destroy the portal and make a new one. If those don't work say something.

Comment: This is just an SMP server between my friends. I'll ask him now!